# Checkbox con apariencia de boton con CSS + icon

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy creando un checkbox que tenga apariencia de un boton con CSS. Está cogiendo bien las clases la label pero tengo un icono dentro de la label que no me cambia el color cuando el input esta checked. Alguna idea de cómo cambiar el color del icono?

```
<div class="checkBtn">
 <input id="checkCarrito" type="checkbox">
 <label for="checkCarrito"><i class="icon-carrito"</i></label>
</div>

.checkBtn label{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 150px; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #82838c;
  margin: 0.5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.checkBtn label:hover {
      background: #dbdcde;
}

.checkBtn input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
  background-color: #17a2b8;
      color: #fff !important;

} 
.checkBtn input[type=checkbox]:checked + label +i{
  background-color: #17a2b8;
      color: #fff !important;

}
.checkBtn input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

El icono se encuentra en otro fichero .css en una carpeta con las fuentes de los iconos.

```
.icon-carrito:before {
    content: "\e903";
    color: #8b8b8b;
}
```

Comment: Es cierto, el + i es incorrecto pero .checkBtn input[type=checkbox]:checked + label i sigue sin cogerme el color :(

Answer (score 1):

Añadiendo `color:inherit` a la clase del icono funciona correctamente

Comment: Hola Maria Jo, me alegra que encontraras una solución al problema. ¿Podrías extender un poco más la respuesta para indicar dónde en el código compartido pusiste eso? Y también una breve descripción de cómo funciona. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes aqui:

`.checkBtn input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + i`

El `<i>` no es el siguiente hermano del `<label>`, si no su hijo, por lo que no deberías de usar el operador +. Te quedaría así:

```
.checkBtn input[type=checkbox]:checked + label i {
  background-color: #17a2b8;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Aun así no me funciona

Comment: Es extraño. ¿La librería que usas de iconos es pública? Y si es así, ¿podrías decirme cómo se llama?

Comment: No es pública, los iconos los he creado yo y creo que puede ser el problema al encontrarse en otro directorio: carpeta icons->style.css, main.css esta al mismo nivel que carpeta icons

Comment: Parece que he dado con la solución. En la clase del icono he puesto color: inherit y ya si me va. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda igualmente!!

Comment: No me había fijado en que le tenías colocado un color al icon. Lo normal es dejar al icono en sí sin color y a lo que le das color es a la la etiqueta `<i>` que lo carga.